# Repair gzipped tar

Tags: gzip

I have a pretty large(50Gb) tar.gz file that I can't untar anymore. Error that I am getting is this:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Is there any way to repair broken tar.gz?

UPDATE: Output of file command:

```
$ file projects.tgz 
projects.tgz: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `file filename.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your file is an uncompressed tarball. The extension `.tgz` is misleading, you might want to give the file a better extension, like `.tar`:

```
mv projects.tgz projects.tar
```

You've possibly tried to extract the file by running:

```
tar xzvf projects.tar
```

But the correct way to extract the tarball is:

```
tar xvf projects.tar
```

Options explained:

- `x`: e**x**tract
- `z`: G**Z**ip compressed (which is not the case in your file, so it should be removed for now)
- `f`: **f**ile (required next argument to be the filename of the archive)
- `v`: Be **v**erbose (show file names while extracting).

See the [manual page on tar](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/tar.1.html) for more information about this command.

Comment: You got uncompress and extract backwards.  Swap them and that will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Rename `projects.tgz` to `projects.tar`. Then you will be able to untar the archive via Nautilus for instance.